# How to use OAuth 'body'=>string like an array? custom API

Tags: php, arrays, string, oauth

I am stuck with string variable which is practically an array. I'm using OAuth to fetch data from my real-estate DB

```
<?php
include_once "oauth-php/library/OAuthStore.php" ;
include_once "oauth-php/library/OAuthRequester.php" ;

$key = '*******'; // this is your consumer key
$secret = '*******'; // this is your consumer secret

$options = ['consumer_key' => $key, 'consumer_secret' => $secret];
OAuthStore::instance("2Leg", $options);

$url = "https://api.zoznamrealit.sk/adverts"; // this is the URL of the request
$method = "GET"; // you can also use POST instead
$params = [];

try {
    // Obtain a request object for the request we want to make
    $request = new OAuthRequester($url, $method, $params);

    // Sign the request, perform a curl request and return the results,
    // throws OAuthException2 exception on an error
    // $result is an array of the form: array ('code'=>int, 'headers'=>array(), 'body'=>string)
    $result = $request->doRequest();

    $response = $result['body'];
} catch(OAuthException2 $e) {
    // handle the exception
}

?>
```

Until now everithing works I guess. my $response looks like this:

```
{"total":"26","adverts":[{"id":"287975","agency_id":"362","internal_id":"PF-1","broker_id":"114035","title_sk":"Rodinný dom s pozemkom vo Veľkom Ďure","title_cz":"Rodinný dům, prodej, Levice, Slovensko","title_en":"Family house, Sale, Levice, Slovakia","title_de":"Einfamilienhaus, zu verkaufen, Levice, Slowakei","title_hu":"Családi ház, eladó, Levice, Szlovákia","title_ru":"","price":"18600.00","show_price":"1","price_unit_id":"21","date_inserted":"2015-08-19 16:56:35","date_last_change":"2015-08-19 17:02:40","latitude":"48.2081728","longitude":"18.445354599999","transaction_id":"11","property_type_id":"61","description_sk":"Ponúkame Vám na predaj rodinný dom v obci Veľký Ďur. Domček je na rovinatom pozemku a za nim sa nachádza veľká záhrada. Pozemok je možné využiť aj na stavbu nového rodinného domu. Na pozemku je zavedený aj obecný vodovod, vlastná studňa, plynová a elektrická prípojka. \r\nV dome je dlhá, vstupná chodba na ktorej konci je kuchyňa so špajzou, 3 izby a miestnosť určená pre kúpeľňu a WC. Strecha je sedlová, okná pôvodné - drevené, tak isto aj vstupné dvere, ďalej podlahy sú taktiež drevené s výnimkou chodby kde je materiál PVC. Domček je v pôvodnom ale zachovalom stave bez nadmernej vlhkosti.\r\n\r\nDom sa nachádza v strede obce s veľmi dobrou občianskou vybavenosťou - 5 minút pešo sa nachádza MŠ, autobusová zastávka, potraviny, pošta aj obecný úrad.\r\n\r\nCena zahŕňa kompletný právny servis pri predaji nehnuteľnosti, vrátane dohodnutia podmienok a vypracovania zmluvy o budúcej kúpnej zmluve, kúpnej zmluvy a návrhu na vklad do katastra nehnuteľností vrátane poplatku za vklad, notárske poplatky pri overovaní podpisov ako aj províziu RK. \r\n\r\nDo pozornosti dávame aj výhody, ktoré kúpou nehnuteľnosti automaticky získavajú. Ich zoznam nájdete na stránke APERTUM Estate \r\n\r\nV prípade záujmu vieme zabezpečiť prostredníctvom spoločnosti APERTUM Consulting aj vybavenie hypotekárneho úveru alebo inej formy financovania ako aj zabezpečenie nehnuteľnosti pre prípad nepredvídateľných udalostí.","description_cz":"","description_en":"","description_de":"","description_hu":"","description_ru":"","show_advert":"1","in_archive":"0","state_id":"1","region_id":"1004","district_id":"10041003","city":"Veľký Ďur","street":"Hlavná","show_street":"1","house_number":"49","exclusive":"0","status_id":"11","ownership_id":"1","condition_id":"3","thermal_insulation_id":"0","furnishing_id":"-1","roof_id":"0","material_id":"1","new_building_id":"0","number_of_rooms":"3","number_of_floors":"1","floor_number":"0","floor_id":"0","internet_id":"0","cable_tv_id":"0","bathroom_id":"9","number_of_bathrooms":"1","heating_id":"111","balcony_id":"0","balcony_area":"0.00","loggia_id":"0","loggia_area":"0.00","terrace_id":"9","terrace_area":"0.00","utility_room_id":"1","utility_room_area":"0.00","garage_id":"9","parking_id":"1","elevator_id":"-1","utilities_id":"-1","waste_disposal_id":"2","water_id":"2","electric_current_id":"1","gas_connection_id":"1","sewer_connection_id":"0","basin_id":"-1","fireplace_id":"2","air_condition_id":"0","energy_performance_certificate_id":"-1","year_of_construction":"0","year_of_building_approval":"0","youtube":"","link":"http://www.apertum.eu/rodinny-dom-s-pozemkom-vo-velkom-dure-287975","is_project":"0","part_of_project":"0","built_up_area":"0","total_area":"0","lot_size":"2200","usable_area":"120","images":[{"id":"16926484","order":"1","url":"http://www.backoffice.sk/fotky/400x320/58/287975_4b120a15a0917124194c28e7ef3ae284.jpg","description":"20150816_183244.jpg"},{"id":"16926482","order":"2","url":"http://www.backoffice.sk/fotky/400x320/58/287975_2c9153e04606c37462694ff987c688b1.jpg","description":"20150816_182223.jpg"},{"id":"16926479","order":"3","url":"http://www.backoffice.sk/fotky/400x320/58/287975_c2a31e39b5cc6d2284db346287e03187.jpg","description":"20150816_182231.jpg"},{"id":"16926481","order":"4","url":"http://www.backoffice.sk/fotky/400x320/58/287975_514531a66c409ad9f8bbc426beb98c30.jpg","description":"20150816_182022.jpg"},{"id":"16926480","order":"5","url":"http://www.backoffice.sk/fotky/400x320/58/287975_440653c4e13c20274ef403b7039a9e60.jpg","description":"20150816_182036.jpg"},{"id":"16926485","order":"6","url":"http://www.backoffice.sk/fotky/400x320/58/287975_b6bf770d2f0fac1f6c3eba3beeeaff98.jpg","description":"20150816_182125.jpg"},{"id":"16926483","order":"7","url":"http://www.backoffice.sk/fotky/400x320/58/287975_949b047688511eec15d555cac9a82342.jpg","description":"20150816_182135.jpg"},{"id":"16926486","order":"8","url":"http://www.backoffice.sk/fotky/400x320/58/287975_24c0939e65aa19f24c0a88e13383ab88.jpg","description":"20150816_182142.jpg"},{"id":"16926487","order":"9","url":"http://www.backoffice.sk/fotky/400x320/58/287975_b1cdf1d5869c467faf667353e9f4a893.jpg","description":"20150816_182157.jpg"}],"price_flags":["fee_included"]},{"id":"286307","agency_id":"362","internal_id":"5/8/15/3","broker_id":"113946","title_sk":"4i DOM S POZEMKOM V TICHEJ LOKALITE","title_cz":"Rodinný dům, prodej, Levice, Slovensko","title_en":"Family house, Sale, Levice, Slovakia","title_de":"Einfamilienhaus, zu verkaufen, Levice, Slowakei","title_hu":"Családi ház, eladó, Levice, Szlovákia","title_ru":"","price":"81000.00","show_price":"1","price_unit_id":"21","date_inserted":"2015-08-05 14:03:17","date_last_change":"2015-08-19 20:42:40","latitude":"48.047092199999","longitude":"18.654566299999","transaction_id":"11","property_type_id":"61","description_sk":"[b]Prízemný nízkoenergetický 4 - izbový dom s jednoduchou sedlovou strechou[/b], alebo s možnosťou výberu atypickej strechy / vhodný aj pre užšie alebo menšie pozemky, nakoľko jeho [b]šírka je 10,5 metra a dĺžka 9,8 metra[/b] / určený pre 2-6 člennú rodinu / možnosť bezbariérového riešenia / možnosť prepojenia obývačky s terasou cez veľké balkónové dvere a tiež zo spálne / kuchyňa je oddelená od obývačky jednoduchou stenou, ktorá je len v strede / možnosť pristavenia špajze vedľa kuchyne / veľkosti všetkých izieb sú štandardné / WC je oddelené od kúpeľne, má svoje okno / kúpeľna má až 8,2 m2 / možnosť otočenia domu zrkadlovo kvôli svetelnej strane / možnosť dodávky krbu umožní dobrý pocit zo sálavého tepla a ušetrí tiež náklady na vykurovanie / [b]dobrý výber stavebných materiálov s tepelno-technickými vlastnosťami je predpokladom minimalizovania spotreby energie na vykurovanie[/b]\r\n\r\nV cene nieje zahrnutá základová doska, nakoľko každý pozemok je individuálny ([i]cena cca: 8 200,- eur[/i])\r\n\r\nmesačné náklady cca 80,- eur\r\n\r\n\r\n[b]Čo všetko zahŕňa cena domu?[/b]\r\n\r\n 1. Panely Obvodové steny: sádrovláknitá doska Fermacell 12,5 mm, konštrukcia z drevených hranolov KVH 140 mm, minerálna vlna dosková 140 mm, parozábranná fólia 0,2 mm, sádrovláknitá doska Fermacell 12,5 mm.\r\n\r\nNosné priečky: sádrovláknitá doska Fermacell 12,5 mm, konštrukcia z drevených hranolov KVH 140 mm, minerálna vlna dosková 140 mm, sádrovláknitá doska Fermacell 12,5 mm.\r\nPriečky: sádrovláknitá doska Fermacell 12,5 mm, konštrukcia z drevených hranolov KVH 100 mm, minerálna vlna dosková 100 mm, sádrovláknitá doska Fermacell 12,5 mm.\r\n2. Fasádny systém\r\nSkladba fasádneho systému na stene (z vonka dnu): Silikátová omietka - ryhovaná so zrnitosťou 2 mm, penetračný náter, sklotextilná sieťka - 145 g, lepidlo, polystyrén EPS 70 - hr.100 mm, lepidlo alebo pena na lepenie polystyrénu, kotviace prvky. Skladba fasádneho systému na podhľadoch (z vonka dnu): Silikátová omietka - ryhovaná so zrnitosťou 2 mm, penetračný náter, sklotextilná sieťka - 145 g, lepidlo, polystyrén EPS 70 - hr.30 mm, lepidlo alebo pena na lepenie polystyrénu, kotviace prvky.\r\n3. Strecha, strešná krytina a odkvapový systém\r\nSkladba (z hora nadol): strešná krytina, latovanie, kontralatovanie, strešná fólia, sústava väzníkov, štíty a podhľady opláštené OSB doskou - hr. 12mm.\r\nTyp strechy: sedlová. Sklon strechy: 22°. Typ krytiny: oceľový plech hr. 0,5 mm, ktorý má 40 ročnú záruku na neprehrdzavenie – značka Ruukki. Farba podľa vzorkovníka.\r\nOdkvapové žľaby a zvody sú z pozinkovaného oceľového plechu, farba podľa vzorkovníka.\r\nPoznámka: Za príplatok 600,- Eur dodáme kvalitnú betónovú krytinu. Vieme dodať aj pálenú krytinu. Cena na základe výberu typu a farby pálenej krytiny.\r\n4. Okná, balkónové a vchodové dvere, parapety\r\n\r\nOkná a balkónové dvere: Profil Geneo od spoločnosti REHAU, stavebná hĺbka 86 mm, tepelno-izolačné trojsklo s teplým rámikom SWISSPACER - Ug=0,6W/m2K, 3 tesnenia, masívna pozinkovaná oceľová armatúra po obvode celého krídla, uzavretá pozinkovaná oceľová armatúra po obvode celého rámu na všetkých oknách aj menších ako 1,5 m. Farba biela.\r\nVonkajšie parapety: Hliníkové hr.2 mm, bočné krytky - hliníkové. Farba parapetov a krytiek - biela.\r\nVnútorné parapety: Plastové. Bočné krytky – plastové. Farba parapetov a krytiek - biela.\r\nVchodové dvere: Zateplené hliníkové dvere s 3 bodovým uzamykaním. Farba biela. Typ výplne zo vzorkovníka štandard.","description_cz":"","description_en":"","description_de":"","description_hu":"","description_ru":"","show_advert":"1","in_archive":"0","state_id":"1","region_id":"1004","district_id":"10041003","city":"Želiezovce","street":"","show_street":"1","house_number":"","exclusive":"0","status_id":"11","ownership_id":"0","condition_id":"7","thermal_insulation_id":"1","furnishing_id":"-1","roof_id":"-1","material_id":"0","new_building_id":"1","number_of_rooms":"4","number_of_floors":"0","floor_number":"0","floor_id":"1","internet_id":"-1","cable_tv_id":"-1","bathroom_id":"1","number_of_bathrooms":"1","heating_id":"9","balcony_id":"9","balcony_area":"0.00","loggia_id":"9","loggia_area":"0.00","terrace_id":"1","terrace_area":"13.53","utility_room_id":"-1","utility_room_area":"0.00","garage_id":"9","parking_id":"-1","elevator_id":"-1","utilities_id":"-1","waste_disposal_id":"-1","water_id":"2","electric_current_id":"1","gas_connection_id":"-1","sewer_connection_id":"-1","basin_id":"-1","fireplace_id":"-1","air_condition_id":"-1","energy_performance_certificate_id":"3","year_of_construction":"0","year_of_building_approval":"0","youtube":"","link":"http://www.apertum.eu/4i-dom-s-pozemkom-v-tichej-lokalite-286307","is_project":"0","part_of_project":"0","built_up_area":"97.4","total_area":"0","lot_size":"1104","usable_area":"82.3","images":[{"id":"16909684","order":"1","url":"http://www.backoffice.sk/fotky/400x320/58/286307_f808d45f598168a1320f48fbe864dd77.jpg","description":"dom s pozemkom želiezovce.jpg"},{"id":"16909612","order":"2","url":"http://www.backoffice.sk/fotky/400x320/58/286307_09c71f425b4ea77663c6982214e51764.jpg","description":"4_big.jpg"},{"id":"16909618","order":"3","url":"http://www.backoffice.sk/fotky/400x320/58/286307_8a7bd1fb66264c06492a4d4b5cf2d688.jpg","description":"11846541_10153121631359150_4774225239026015137_n.jpg"},{"id":"16909619","order":"4","url":"http://www.backoffice.sk/fotky/400x320/58/286307_1e69d31ec0de7fa8c7fddf70b795e03f.jpg","description":"11828631_10153121631639150_425989980888665035_n.jpg"},{"id":"16909617","order":"5","url":"http://www.backoffice.sk/fotky/400x320/58/286307_b966b54babb01554000dd58ce6c75536.jpg","description":"11811455_10153121631269150_2669924782051680500_n.jpg"},{"id":"16909613","order":"6","url":"http://www.backoffice.sk/fotky/400x320/58/286307_6eabc8924c52c973c54f95112b71dd19.jpg","description":"10982002_10153121631414150_5865845897765845067_n.jpg"},{"id":"16909615","order":"7","url":"http://www.backoffice.sk/fotky/400x320/58/286307_b2327adea20fa2b9a060029f040b0460.jpg","description":"11800295_10153121631339150_1325144115751094887_n.jpg"},{"id":"16909616","order":"8","url":"http://www.backoffice.sk/fotky/400x320/58/286307_43f05fb66fc32e9ec117aedd2bb9a221.jpg","description":"11800431_10153121631319150_2649385207762035839_n.jpg"},{"id":"16909620","order":"9","url":"http://www.backoffice.sk/fotky/400x320/58/286307_26fcbba9649a371ce395a4e27b6a15e3.png","description":"pod.png"},{"id":"16909614","order":"10","url":"http://www.backoffice.sk/fotky/400x320/58/286307_5c1604444d2ce421d71fb3e54744d4db.jpg","description":"11796192_10153121631229150_3877333200958234697_n.jpg"},{"id":"16909609","order":"11","url":"http://www.backoffice.sk/fotky/400x320/58/286307_c8aca5e0fcb0fbbdc04f61c0a08e8cab.jpg","description":"5_big.jpg"},{"id":"16909610","order":"12","url":"http://www.backoffice.sk/fotky/400x320/58/286307_44e323408f9c356dfda11dae71e4c7a1.jpg","description":"7_big.jpg"},{"id":"16909637","order":"13","url":"http://www.backoffice.sk/fotky/400x320/58/286307_928726da3621b07b12f459632724d9a2.jpg","description":"želiezovce fin logo.jpg"}],"price_flags":[""]},{"id":"286303","agency_id":"362","internal_id":"5/8/15/2","broker_id":"114095","title_sk":"Stavebný pozemok v tichom prostredí PRIPRAVENÝ NA VÝSTAVBU","title_cz":"Pozemky - bydlení, prodej, Levice, Slovensko","title_en":"Land – for living, Sale, Levice, Slovakia","title_de":"Baugrund, zu verkaufen, Levice, Slowakei","title_hu":"Építési telek, eladó, Levice, Szlovákia","title_ru":"","price":"21500.00","show_price":"1","price_unit_id":"21","date_inserted":"2015-08-05 13:31:40","date_last_change":"2015-08-05 13:31:40","latitude":"48.053663909819","longitude":"18.662146478891","transaction_id":"11","property_type_id":"41","description_sk":"Ponúkame Vám na predaj Stavebný pozemok v tichej lokalite v obci Želiezovce.\r\nPozemok je vyčistený a pripravený na výstavbu. Na pozemku sa nachádza studňa a el. prípojka, neďaleko pozemku je aj plynová prípojka\r\n","description_cz":"","description_en":"","description_de":"","description_hu":"","description_ru":"","show_advert":"1","in_archive":"0","state_id":"1","region_id":"1004","district_id":"10041003","city":"Želiezovce","street":"","show_street":"0","house_number":"","exclusive":"0","status_id":"11","ownership_id":"0","condition_id":"0","thermal_insulation_id":"-1","furnishing_id":"-1","roof_id":"-1","material_id":"0","new_building_id":"-1","number_of_rooms":"","number_of_floors":"0","floor_number":"0","floor_id":"0","internet_id":"-1","cable_tv_id":"-1","bathroom_id":"9","number_of_bathrooms":"1","heating_id":"9","balcony_id":"9","balcony_area":"0.00","loggia_id":"9","loggia_area":"0.00","terrace_id":"9","terrace_area":"0.00","utility_room_id":"-1","utility_room_area":"0.00","garage_id":"9","parking_id":"-1","elevator_id":"-1","utilities_id":"1","waste_disposal_id":"-1","water_id":"2","electric_current_id":"1","gas_connection_id":"1","sewer_connection_id":"-1","basin_id":"-1","fireplace_id":"-1","air_condition_id":"-1","energy_performance_certificate_id":"-1","year_of_construction":"0","year_of_building_approval":"0","youtube":"","link":"http://www.apertum.eu/stavebny-pozemok-v-tichom-prostredi-pripraveny-na-vystavbu-286303","is_project":"0","part_of_project":"0","built_up_area":"0","total_area":"0","lot_size":"1104","usable_area":"0","images":[{"id":"16909554","order":"1","url":"http://www.backoffice.sk/fotky/400x320/58/286303_7c71ccd75fc51893d6864804241f6f0e.jpg","description":"želiezovce fin logo.jpg"}],"price_flags":[""]},{"id":"286261","agency_id":"362","internal_id":"5.9.2015","broker_id":"114140","title_sk":"Pekný 3- izbový byt v blízkosti SANAT-u","title_cz":"Byt 3+1, prodej, Levice, Slovensko","title_en":"Two bedroom apartment, Sale, Levice, Slovakia","title_de":"3 Zimmer Wohnung, zu verkaufen, Levice, Slowakei","title_hu":"3 szobás lakás, eladó, Levice, Szlovákia","title_ru":"","price":"42800.00","show_price":"1","price_unit_id":"21","date_inserted":"2015-08-05 11:12:49","date_last_change":"2015-08-24 20:32:37","latitude":"48.213732","longitude":"18.609317799999","transaction_id":"11","property_type_id":"122","description_sk":"Ponúkame Vám na predaj pekný 3-izbový byt v blízkosti zdravotníckeho zariadenia SANAT.\r\nByt prešiel kompletnou rekonštrukciou. Bytový dom sa momentálne zatepluje.\r\nK bytu patria dva veľké pivničné priestory. \r\n\r\nByt je prístupný kedykoľvek neváhajte ma kontaktovať.\r\n","description_cz":"","description_en":"","description_de":"","description_hu":"","description_ru":"","show_advert":"1","in_archive":"0","state_id":"1","region_id":"1004","district_id":"10041003","city":"Levice","street":"Kpt. Nálepku","show_street":"0","house_number":"","exclusive":"0","status_id":"11","ownership_id":"1","condition_id":"1","thermal_insulation_id":"1","furnishing_id":"-1","roof_id":"-1","material_id":"1","new_building_id":"0","number_of_rooms":"4","number_of_floors":"4","floor_number":"4","floor_id":"0","internet_id":"-1","cable_tv_id":"-1","bathroom_id":"3","number_of_bathrooms":"1","heating_id":"9","balcony_id":"11","balcony_area":"0.00","loggia_id":"9","loggia_area":"0.00","terrace_id":"9","terrace_area":"0.00","utility_room_id":"1","utility_room_area":"0.00","garage_id":"9","parking_id":"11","elevator_id":"0","utilities_id":"-1","waste_disposal_id":"-1","water_id":"-1","electric_current_id":"-1","gas_connection_id":"-1","sewer_connection_id":"-1","basin_id":"-1","fireplace_id":"-1","air_condition_id":"-1","energy_performance_certificate_id":"-1","year_of_construction":"0","year_of_building_approval":"0","youtube":"","link":"http://www.apertum.eu/pekny-3-izbovy-byt-v-blizkosti-sanat-u-286261","is_project":"0","part_of_project":"0","built_up_area":"0","total_area":"0","lot_size":"0","usable_area":"65.4","images":[{"id":"16909024","order":"1","url":"http://www.backoffice.sk/fotky/400x320/58/286261_dda902739e6215911e3fff4221d8a3b6.jpg","description":"DSCN1331.JPG"},{"id":"16909027","order":"2","url":"http://www.backoffice.sk/fotky/400x320/58/286261_eb94c74a7bdfac7a96703b1646a6cf4c.jpg","description":"DSCN1322.JPG"},{"id":"16909025","order":"3","url":"http://www.backoffice.sk/fotky/400x320/58/286261_f0cd1976ea981eecf3917bb9842351d4.jpg","description":"DSCN1330.JPG"},{"id":"16909022","order":"4","url":"http://www.backoffice.sk/fotky/400x320/58/286261_78c0d00ef37c259ea5e47926960c647d.jpg","description":"DSCN1318.JPG"},{"id":"16909019","order":"5","url":"http://www.backoffice.sk/fotky/400x320/58/286261_ff4b14acda20a6f9b18766acaddb5953.jpg","description":"DSCN1320.JPG"},{"id":"16909026","order":"6","url":"http://www.backoffice.sk/fotky/400x320/58/286261_5ba345b86f3dcd3783173e55d6d204fe.jpg","description":"DSCN1341.JPG"},{"id":"16909028","order":"7","url":"http://www.backoffice.sk/fotky/400x320/58/286261_a4976a61ce2dcd4de54a797292f660b8.jpg","description":"DSCN1344.JPG"},{"id":"16909020","order":"8","url":"http://www.backoffice.sk/fotky/400x320/58/286261_21c2b8370575200e215ce1fee3cfddb7.jpg","description":"DSCN1302.JPG"},{"id":"16909021","order":"9","url":"http://www.backoffice.sk/fotky/400x320/58/286261_eeead9d3807c93afb3202978388db169.jpg","description":"DSCN1312.JPG"},{"id":"16909263","order":"10","url":"http://www.backoffice.sk/fotky/400x320/58/286261_e7d3a1fd34bee8871a7036d13ce01caf.jpg","description":"DSCN1308.JPG"},{"id":"16909023","order":"11","url":"http://www.backoffice.sk/fotky/400x320/58/286261_15dd81cbfafefb5782c541a68f16af0b.jpg","description":"zadná časť.jpg"}],"price_flags":[""]}]}
```

And that's the problem.

Here is part from my custom API documentation:

> RESOURCES  GET
>   /adverts{?property_type_id,district_id,transaction_id,state_id,region_id,min_price,max_price,min_area,max_area,part_of_project,fulltext,development,limit,offset,advert_id,img_quality,in_archive,fields,img_limit}
>   Parameters property_type_id integer (optional)  Possible to send
>   multiple ID’s as an array
>
> district_id integer (optional)  Possible to send multiple ID’s as an
>   array
>
> transaction_id integer (optional)  state_id integer (optional) 
>   region_id integer (optional)  min_price float (optional)  max_price
>   float (optional)  min_area float (optional)  max_area float (optional)
>   part_of_project integer (optional)  ID of the project
>
> fulltext string (optional)  development integer (optional)  filter
>   development projects only
>
> limit integer (optional) Default: 20  Number of adverts per result
>   set.
>
> offset integer (optional) Default: 0  Offset of the result set
>
> advert_id integer (optional)  Possible to send multiple ID’s as an
>   array
>
> img_quality string (optional) Default: xxxhdpi  Values: - mdpi
>   (100x80px), hdpi (150x120px), xhdpi (200x160px), xxhdpi (300x240px),
>   xxxhdpi (400x320px)
>
> in_archive integer (optional)  Limit adverts to only archived (1) or
>   only not archived (0). Default showing all.
>
> fields string (optional)  Comma separated list of fields to be
>   included in the result. id is always included.
>
> img_limit integer (optional)  Number of images to return.
>
> Response  200 Hide Headers
>
> Content-Type: application/json Body
>
> {
>       "total": 28,
>       "adverts": [
>           {
>               "id": 123,
>               "title_sk": "2 izbový byt, Staré Mesto, Bratislava",
>               ...
>           },
>           {
>               "id": 653,
>               "title_sk": "3 izbový byt, Staré Mesto, Bratislava",
>               ...
>           }
>       ] }

And now to the problem :)

how can I use the long bloody $response STRING? Best for me would be converting it into an array but I dunno how to do it with such a long string.

**Thank you all in advance for the solution.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's JSON, so you can just do this:

`$array = json_decode($response, true);`

The true on the end makes it into an array (rather than an object)

See the [json_decode manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)  for more info.